# Answer to two processes

Tags: erlang

I have three nodes and each one in a console. One is the server and the other two are the clients. When a client sends a message to the server, the server must send another message to the clients but it only appears in the console of the client who sent the message.

Why the message doesn´t appear in the other node? Thanks.

Comment: The Erlang shell prints messages you send immediately, which is likely what you are observing. Did you connect to the other nodes?

Comment: How do you print the messages in the client consoles? The shell only automatically prints the return values from the expressions it evaluates.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Erlang distributed programming tutorial I do not find anything better than this: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/distribunomicon.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for [flush/0](http://erldocs.com/R16B03/stdlib/c.html?i=4&search=flush#flush/0).
The message are received by the different nodes, but are most likely kept in the queue.
The above function will print and empty said queue.

On the other node's shell, just

```
> flush().
```